# Why the text of TextView not changing when I click appropriate button

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in Android Development (Java) and I need some help.
Why the text of TextView not changing when I click appropriate button.
Logcat shows nothing also.

```
TextView textView;
EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contacts);

    Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnShowName);
    editText = (EditText )this.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

For [Jaz] Layout  'activity_view_contacts' of activity is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication3.app.ViewContactsActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Name"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowName"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens to the log print? Is it print there?

Comment: There is nothing printing in logcat

Comment: Can you post your activity_view_contacts file as well?

Comment: try to make textView Final. Try to do textView.setText("Hello"), and see if that works.

Comment: String myText=editText.getText().toString();  textView.setText(myText);//try this

Comment: Hi Jaz. I have added layout to post. aafonso1991 - I have checked  textView.setText("Hello") by insterting it on the close of OnCreate - not helps. It seems like this code never executing.

Comment: Sania! Hallo! :( not helps

Comment: clean your project once and run it again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare the Button outside of the onCreate function like you did with the TwxtView and EditText? You're loosing your 'btn' as soon as onCreate returns.

Comment: unfortunately not helps :(

Answer (score 0):

Delete 'this' from all 3 'editText = (EditText )this.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);' and leave it like 'editText = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);' give that a try

And something i noticed now, Remove View from new View.OnClickListener().

Comment: I tried make 'Button btn' Global, but without result.

Comment: Try removing 'this' also. Not sure if that helps, but i never used it in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnShowName);
    editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

}
```

and the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.geronimo.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShowName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Show Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowName"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works for me.So i'd just say just check your imports once and maybe cross check with this code?

Comment: And something which usually fixes these errors for me.Try cleaning the project :)

Comment: Thank you to all, folks! I guess problem in the IDE. In Eclipse all running as i need. (I used Android Studio)